# Calculating the number of digits in sensor reading (Arduino)

Tags: arduino

I am creating arduino project which checks the temperature and sends the data to Xively protal. I've found some examples, but I do not understand the number of digits in sensor reading method. Could anyone explain it to me ? Especially the part with dividend / 10 ?

The method is:

```
//This method calulates the number of digits in the sensor readind
//Since each digit of the ASCII decimal representation is a byte, the number
//of digits equals the numbers of bytes:

int getLength(int someValue)
{
//there's at least one byte:
int digits = 1;
//continually divide the value by ten, adding one to the digit count for
//each time you divide, until you are at 0
int getLength(int someValue) {
int digits = 1; 
int dividend = someValue /10 ;
while (dividend > 0) {
  dividend = dividend /10;
  digits++; 
}
return digits;
}
```

I would really appreciate any explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  If I have the number 1234 and I want to know how many digits are there?  Well I start with 1 because I know there is at least 1.  Then I divide by 10, that gives me 123.  That's greater than 0 so I know that there was at least one more digit.  Then I divide by ten and that gives me 12, that's greater than ten so I know that there is at least one more digit.  Divide again by 10 and I get 1.  That is greater than 0 so that's one more digit.  Divide again by ten and I get 0.  Now I know I have counted off all the digits in 1234.

Basically you are using the divide by ten to remove the last digit of the number.  If that leaves you still with a number then there are more digits.  Do that over and over until you get to 0.  Once you get to 0 you have chewed them all up and are done counting.

It's just math, not anything esoteric to programming.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you! To clarify for anyone, be sure that if you're using a floating point or double that you're looking for a final number `< 1 and not equal`!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Delta_G's answer, here is the solution visualized in C++ ⤵︎

```cpp
int currentNumberOfDigits = 0;
int number = 439348;

while (number != 0) {
 number = number / 10;
 currentNumberOfDigits++;
}

return currentNumberOfDigits; // 6 Digits
```

This is a good alternative to using a string because this way you can use up less storage on your Arduino because you can use other data types rather than a string!

Here is an example of the sizes of other data types ⤵︎

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string, and measure length of string to get numbers of digit.
Below under Arduino IDE code

```
void setup() {
}
int numb = 1234;
void loop(){
  String yourText=String (numb);
  Serial.print(yourText.length());  // get 4 digit
}
```